# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure what's causing the error. Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT ( SUM(DWXP050.Premp) )
FROM   DWXP050
       LEFT JOIN [DWXP050 GL Class]
         ON [DWXP050 GL Class].Policy = DWXP050.Policy
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].CDDESC = DWXP050.CDDESC
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].TRDATE = DWXP050.TRDATE
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] = DWXP050.EFFDTE
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB = DWXP050.ASLOB
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].AGENT = DWXP050.AGENT
WHERE  (( ( DWXP050.TRANS ) = '10'
           OR ( DWXP050.TRANS ) = '20' ))
GROUP  BY ( SUM(DWXP050.Premp) )
HAVING ( ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].AGENT ) = '00000BP001' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] ) >= '20130201'
               AND ( [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] ) <= '20130228' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB ) = '170'
                OR ( [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB ) = '180' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].[Product] ) <> 'CUP' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].CDDESC ) = 'PEST CONTROL SERVICES' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].TRDATE ) <= '20130401' ) )
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.   You are `SUM`ing and `GROUP`ing by the same column.  Just take out your `GROUP BY` since I suspect it's unneeded.

Comment: If I take that out I get these errors:                            Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.AGENT' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.Effective Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.Effective Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.ASLOB' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.ASLOB' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Things in your HAVING clause that are not using aggregate functions need to be moved to your WHERE clause.

Comment: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.Product' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.CDDESC' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'DWXP050 GL Class.TRDATE' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The HAVING clause is meant to test predicates on aggregated (e.g. SUMmed) data. All the predicates you're using should go in the WHERE clause. In short, you don't need GROUP BY or HAVING if all you're doing is selecting a SUM().

Answer (score 0):

You are using the HAVING clause like a WHERE clause.  That is, you are trying to enforce data constraints that are NOT on aggregate or GROUP BY expressions.  Move them to your WHERE clause instead.

```
SELECT ( SUM(DWXP050.Premp) )
FROM   DWXP050
       LEFT JOIN [DWXP050 GL Class]
         ON [DWXP050 GL Class].Policy = DWXP050.Policy
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].CDDESC = DWXP050.CDDESC
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].TRDATE = DWXP050.TRDATE
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] = DWXP050.EFFDTE
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB = DWXP050.ASLOB
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].AGENT = DWXP050.AGENT
WHERE  (( ( DWXP050.TRANS ) = '10'
           OR ( DWXP050.TRANS ) = '20' ))
AND ( ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].AGENT ) = '00000BP001' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] ) >= '20130201'
               AND ( [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] ) <= '20130228' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB ) = '170'
                OR ( [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB ) = '180' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].[Product] ) <> 'CUP' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].CDDESC ) = 'PEST CONTROL SERVICES' )
         AND ( ( [DWXP050 GL Class].TRDATE ) <= '20130401' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an aggregate function in your GROUP BY clause and non-aggregate filters in your HAVING clause.  Since you're SUMming on the same column you seem to ant to group by, just take the group out and move the HAVING statements to your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT SUM(DWXP050.Premp)
FROM   DWXP050
       LEFT JOIN [DWXP050 GL Class]
         ON [DWXP050 GL Class].Policy = DWXP050.Policy
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].CDDESC = DWXP050.CDDESC
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].TRDATE = DWXP050.TRDATE
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] = DWXP050.EFFDTE
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB = DWXP050.ASLOB
            AND [DWXP050 GL Class].AGENT = DWXP050.AGENT
WHERE  
    ( DWXP050.TRANS  = '10'
           OR  DWXP050.TRANS  = '20' )
    AND [DWXP050 GL Class].AGENT  = '00000BP001' 
    AND [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] >= '20130201'
    AND [DWXP050 GL Class].[Effective Date] <= '20130228'
    AND ([DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB  = '170'
        OR [DWXP050 GL Class].ASLOB = '180' )
    AND [DWXP050 GL Class].[Product] ) <> 'CUP'
    AND [DWXP050 GL Class].CDDESC = 'PEST CONTROL SERVICES'
    AND [DWXP050 GL Class].TRDATE <= '20130401'
```